# Div error con ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Lo que sucede es que al enviar el formulario, si hay un error se muestra un mensaje en un div, esto solamente ocurre la primera vez, luego sigo presionando el submit, pero no me aparece el mensaje de error.

funcion ajax:

```
function login(){
    login.submit();
}

function ValidarRequeridos(){

divResultado        = document.getElementById("resultado");
var Usuario         = document.getElementById("Usuario").value;
var Password        = document.getElementById("Password").value;
ajax = newAjax();   


ajax.open("POST", "login_verify.php",true);
ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (ajax.readyState==4) {
        //mostrar resultados en esta capa
  divResultado.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
  $("#resultado").delay(2000).hide(300);


}
}
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
//enviando los valores
ajax.send("Usuario="+Usuario+"&Password="+Password);    


};
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos el código que tienes actualmente? Ahora mismo es imposible que podamos ayudarte si no vemos el código que tienes hecho.

Comment: lo siento, lo estaba editando. creo que el problema puede ser el hide(), la verdad no estoy muy familiarizado con ajax y javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tras mostrar el mensaje la primera vez ocultas el div `#resultado`, pero en ningún momento vuelves a mostrarlo.

Por eso cuando vuelve a producirse el error, sí cambias el contenido del div asignándoselo a la propiedad `innerHTML` pero en ningún momento indicas que el div deba mostrarse.

Deberías utilizar el método `show` para ello:

```
    //mostrar resultados en esta capa
divResultado.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
$("#resultado").show();
$("#resultado").delay(2000).hide(300);
```

Comment: muchas gracias, eso era, sabía que ese era el problema, porque lo estaba ocultando, pero después no lo mostraba.